# How to send scheduled email in javascript?

Tags: javascript, email, smtp, gmail, schedule

I'm using SMTPJS to send emails by Gmail SMTP. Here my simple work code:

```
<script src="https://smtpjs.com/v2/smtp.js"></script>

sendEmail(to, subject, body){ 
    Email.send(
        "SITENAME noti.sitename@gmail.com", //from
        to, //to
        subject, //subject
        body,   //body
        "smtp.gmail.com", //smtp host
        "noti.sitename@gmail.com", //username account
        "Noti-Password",    //password account
        message=>{
            alert("sent");
        }
    )
}
```

What I need to do is sending an email that should be sent by date. For example after 2 weeks or after 30 days. So is that possible by adding some lines or doing an other way ?

Comment: You can run cron on a server and use node.js - in a web page, the page has to be open at the time of the sending

Comment: I don't think this is possible on a website front-end, it would require the person to keep the page open for the amount of time to send the email. As once you close the page, the script stops. I believe you would need to do this on a backend server.

Comment: You should switch either to node.js or some other programming language that you can keep open/client doesn't have to run it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do this in the Front End because JavaScript on the browser is only executed while the site is opened.

To do it you need a server to run a code every X time, that's a cron.
That code can be written in languages such as Python, JavaScript (Node.js) o PHP.

If you can host that on a website you probably can also run PHP so I recommend you to use PHP. This is how you would do it:

1. In your HTML [use a Form to send the content of the email via POST](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_form.asp) to a PHP file.
2. Upload a PHP file that reads the [POST parameters](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php) and [saves a file](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_create.asp) (for example a JSON) that contains, for each email: the timestamp in which should be sent and the email content.
3. Upload a PHP file that reads the "pending emails to send" file and [sends the emails](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mail_mail.asp) that have a past timestamp and removes that mail from the file.
4. Set up a cron that runs the second PHP file every one day at 8am.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's not possible with only JavaScript For this you need to open your browser for that specific time it can be manage from the server side but as far my concern from client side it can be done  with extension only that must be embedded in client browser. You can you use background or cantent script to send the message at the particular time